# Storing multiple versions of a value in DB

Tags: sql, database, database-design

A DB design question.

I need to design an item with multiple versions of the same value, like a shoping cart product in a multilingual store.

Say I have a product

```
CREATE TABLE product 
 id INT,
 name VARCHAR(64),
 description SMALLTEXT,
 whatever BOOL,
 another INT;
```

and a translation table

```
CREATE TABLE product_language
 product_id INT,
 language_id INT,
 name VARCHAR(64),
 descripton SMALLTEXT;
```

Now my question is... is table `product` sensible or not? Most of  the shops will be 1 language only, so does it make sense to keep name and description in default language in `product` table to avoid `JOINs` when there is only one language on the system? Or will it give me headaches I can not foresee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the JOIN to get the product_language would be inconsequential. RDBMs are really good at executing performant joins :). I don't see any benefit to using a "default" name and description. You'd have to synchronize the value and/or have special handling in your application to show the default name and description if no matching language-specific is available.